# Zendesk App Tools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app

I am following this blog to setup zendesk environment in my machine.
https://help.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/229489288

When I try to execute this command

> gem install zendesk_apps_tools

I get the error [image]

Your help will be much appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: This error appears when there is an issue with your network connection or rubygems.org is down. If you're sure your internet connection is ok, you can check the status of rubygems.org, e.g., https://twitter.com/rubygems_status?lang=en

Comment: @mzh there is lots of data that gem requires to download. Ensure that you have a good internet connection and no firewall/gateway is blocking your internet connection.